# How to use two formulas at the same time?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, conditional-formatting, formulas

How to format column C (with grey background and red font) if in column C we find the name "POPA" and in column E we find the letter "E" at the same time?

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeiSs.png

Comment: In the conditional format formula put `=AND(C2 = "POPA",E2 = "E")`

Comment: @ScottCraner I have tryed this and its not working                          =AND(C2:C726 = "POPA",E2:E726 = "E")

Comment: Put the one I stated above exactly as it is typed and make the `Applies To:` C2:C726

Comment: @ScottCraner http://i.imgur.com/hJUbN96.png Still not working ( row 505 )

Comment: While C2 is selected.  Go to Conditional Formatting -->Manage Rules.  Add New Rule.  Choose formula. Paste formula. Change format to desired.  Hit OK.  In Applies to Put `=C2:C726`.  Hit apply.  It works for me.

Comment: Nevermind I realize your problem is you are looking at part of the string

Comment: @ScottCraner https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_ODHvYyGCLUaUdkbzJWUkxxVkU It's exactly how you said it but still not working . Anyway ... Thank's a lot for thelp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please select ColumnC and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(SEARCH("*POPA*",C1)>0,E1="E")
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select grey fill and red font, OK, OK.

This is case insensitive.

Comment: Yeah, I just looked at his data an realized he wanted to look at part of the cell.  My bad for thinking that he put everything in his description

Comment: @pnuts Thank you a lot

Comment: @pnuts I will need help with a few more formulas .. How can I contact you my friend ?

Comment: @pnuts I need a formula to calculate the percentage of "promovat" from column G http://i.imgur.com/aAl4rsn.png ( 75 % )

Comment: And I don't have 20 rep to start a chat with you :(